# node module include data file as a global variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I set out to make my first node module. It's very simple, it just takes the input from a user and validates if it is valid or not by comparing it to a large data file. The data file is just a json object. Here is the code for index.js

```
// borrowed heavily from http://quickleft.com/blog/creating-and-publishing-a-node-js-module
/**
* Valiate a NAICS codes using 2012 NAICS codes
*
* @param  {String} 2 to 6 digit numeric
* @return {Boolean}
*/

var fs = require('fs');
var obj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('codes.json', 'utf8'));

module.exports = {
  validateNAICS: function(inNAICS) {

    inNAICS = inNAICS || "";
    if (inNAICS.length > 6) { return false };
    if (inNAICS.length < 2) { return false };
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(inNAICS)) { return true };
    return false;
  },

  /**
  * Given a NAICS code return the industry name
  *
  * @param  {String} 2 to 6 digit numeric
  * @return {String}
  */

  translateNAICS: function(inNAICS) {
    inNAICS = inNAICS || "000";

    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(inNAICS)) { return obj[inNAICS] };

    return "Unknown";
  }
};
```

However, when I try to use this in a project, the code seems to look for `codes.js` in the project's root rather than in the modules root. I was able to prove this by making a copy of `codes.js` and putting it in the project's root and everything worked as expected.

So what is the proper way to include the data from `codes.js` so that it is available to my two functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to simply `require` it via a relative path name:

```
var obj = require('./codes.json');
```

Requires are always relative to the module itself, not the current working directory. [Node.js understand that this is a JSON file](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules) and parses it accordingly.

In general, you can get a reference to the directory the module is in via the [**`__dirname`**](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname) variable. So the following works as well:

```
var path = require('path');
var obj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'codes.json'), 'utf8'));
```